# Cat won't use litter box

Tags: cats, toilet-training

My 6 year old cat has stopped using her litter box after my other cat died. She is going on the floor or in her food dish. When I took her down to the litter box to try and reintroduce her to it she tensed up as soon as we got into the room the litter box was in. I don't know how to get her to use the box again.

Comment: Hi Kelly, there are a few questions already around this topic, including the one that I indicated this is a duplicate of. Look at the list of related questions to the side of the page as well.